# Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined(…)

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

After inspecting an element, I see this very often-

[image]

I then have to switch over to **AngularJS tab in Google Chrome** and then click the **checkbox Enable** as seen clearly in the attached image. I don't know why it keeps on switching off after sometime.

[image]

It does have a material impact atleast on the application I am working. The moment I switch over to AngularJS tab (so as to enable the very same checkbox aforementioned), the whole application gets refreshed **(Ctrl+F5)** automatically gets invoked.

It's a disaster for me as the application which I am developing has around **5 to 6 steps**. And I do have to cry when I have to inspect an element on step6 and when sometimes there is: **$scope is not defined**. All the values gets lost since after automatical refresh, the application swill get navigated to step-1.

This happens with the browsers for all the fellow associates in the team. This just makes us nervous.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to debug a specific scope in your app?

Comment: stop script execution using chrome dev tools

Comment: @AranS: To inspect any field on the UI to get to know its data-ng-model being on $scope, atleast first $scope has to come defined. Right.

Comment: you have two questions mixed as one here.  First, you seem to have a question about the functionality of the angularjs batarang tool, which has been broken for a very long time (most people don't even recommend using it at all).  the second question seems to be about how to debug one of your specific steps in your application.  You may want to separate these into different questions, and provide code illustrating the section you are having errors in.